# When converting to libtool automake and autoconf can't find libtool

Tags: c, macos, autoconf, automake, libtool

I'm trying to convert libcsv to use libtool so I can use it on mac os x without mangling the makefile.  When I try to run the makefile generated from the tools I get the following error:

```
~/software/libcsv (gnu_tools) $ make 
tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\"
-DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"libcsv\" 
-DVERSION=\"3.0.1\" -I.     -g -O2 -MT libcsv.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libcsv.Tpo -c -o libcsv.lo  
libcsv.c
/bin/sh: --mode=compile: command not found
make: [libcsv.lo] Error 127 (ignored)
mv -f .deps/libcsv.Tpo .deps/libcsv.Plo
mv: rename .deps/libcsv.Tpo to .deps/libcsv.Plo: No such file or directory
make: *** [libcsv.lo] Error 1
```

I'm running OS X 10.5.  So after a little fossicking about I noticed that the makefile generated has an empty libtool var:

```
<generated makefile>
LD = 
LDFLAGS = 
LIBOBJS = 
LIBS = 
LIBTOOL = 
LIPO = 
LN_S = 
LTLIBOBJS = 
<more generated makefile>
```

If I set LIBTOOL to libtool, then all is well.  I assume I've made a mistake in my autoconf or automake files which are below:

```
Makefile.am
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libcsv.la
libcsv_la_SOURCES = libcsv.c
include_HEADERS = csv.h
libcsv_la_LDFLAGS = -version-info 3:1:0
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4

configure.ac
dn1 Process this file with autoconf to produce a configure script.
AC_INIT(libcsv.c)
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(libcsv, 3.0.1)
AC_PROG_CC
AC_OUTPUT(Makefile)
AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([strerror])
AC_FUNC_MALLOC
C_PROG_RANLIB
AC_PROG_CXX
LT_INIT
LT_OUTPUT
AC_TYPE_SIZE_T
```

If it's any help here is part of the config.log:

```
## ------------------ ##
## Running config.lt. ##
## ------------------ ##
config.lt:680: creating libtool
configure:17115: checking for size_t
configure:17115: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
configure:17115: $? = 0
configure:17115: gcc -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
conftest.c: In function 'main':
conftest.c:62: error: syntax error before ')' token
configure:17115: $? = 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "libcsv"
| #define VERSION "3.0.1"
| #define STDC_HEADERS 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_SYS_STAT_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRING_H 1
| #define HAVE_MEMORY_H 1
| #define HAVE_STRINGS_H 1
| #define HAVE_INTTYPES_H 1
| #define HAVE_STDINT_H 1
| #define HAVE_UNISTD_H 1
| #define HAVE_DLFCN_H 1
| #define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
| #define HAVE_STRERROR 1
| #define HAVE_STDLIB_H 1
| #define HAVE_MALLOC 1
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <stdio.h>
| #ifdef HAVE_SYS_TYPES_H
| # include <sys/types.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_SYS_STAT_H
| # include <sys/stat.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef STDC_HEADERS
| # include <stdlib.h>
| # include <stddef.h>
| #else
| # ifdef HAVE_STDLIB_H
| #  include <stdlib.h>
| # endif
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_STRING_H
| # if !defined STDC_HEADERS && defined HAVE_MEMORY_H
| #  include <memory.h>
| # endif
| # include <string.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_STRINGS_H
| # include <strings.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_INTTYPES_H
| # include <inttypes.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_STDINT_H
| # include <stdint.h>
| #endif
| #ifdef HAVE_UNISTD_H
| # include <unistd.h>
| #endif
| int
| main ()
| {
| if (sizeof ((size_t)))
|       return 0;
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:17115: result: yes
```

So does anyone know what I've done wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I dont have a definite answer for you, but the first thing I'd suggst is to put your `AC_OUTPUT` at the end of your `configure.ac`, after the `LT_INIT`.  It's not *completely* this simple, but it's not far wrong to think of the contents of `configure.ac` as expanding in turn to fragments of shell script that are executed in turn.  If you emit the configured `Makefile` before you've found `libtool`, then that could explain `LIBTOOL` being empty.

A fairly conventional layout of your `configure.ac` would be the following:

```
dnl Process this file with autoconf to produce a configure script.
AC_INIT(libcsv.c)
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(libcsv, 3.0.1)
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])

dnl find programs
AC_PROG_CC
AC_PROG_CXX
LT_INIT
AC_PROG_RANLIB

dnl check functionality
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([strerror])
AC_FUNC_MALLOC
AC_TYPE_SIZE_T

AC_OUTPUT(Makefile)
```

I don't think you needed `LT_OUTPUT`, and the [docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/LT_005fINIT.html) note that `AC_PROG_LIBTOOL` is a deprecated synonym for `LT_INIT` (so having both is probably asking for trouble).

(Apropos of nothing very much, note that OS X has a command called `libtool`, which is nothing to do with GNU Libtool.  I'm pretty sure that's not your problem here, but it's a gotcha that's confused people before)

Comment: Norman, thanks so much for that.  Moving AC_OUTPUT to the end of the file and then removing AC_PROG_LIBTOOL did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to re-enforce the libtool integration by running `libtoolize --force` (I had a lot of trouble with different incomatible libtool versions on different hosts, libtoolize --force helps a lot in such cases). Also watch out the configure output for libtool messages, they must read like this:

```
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
configure: creating libtool
appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
appending configuration tag "F77" to libtool
```

especially the `configure: creating libtool` line must be present in the output.

Comment: Hi Rudi,

Thanks for responding.  I re-ran libtoolize --force and observed the following in the output:
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
configure: creating ./config.lt
config.lt: creating libtool
checking for size_t... yes

Same response in the make step though so that hasn't fixed it I'm afraid.

Comment: You can run the configure script with more verbose output by executing `sh -x configure`, and search the output for `LIBTOOL=`. Also look for `LIBTOOL=` lines in configure(there should be a `# Always use our own libtool.` line above). BTW: with which version of autoconf was the configure script created(configure --help)? Maybe the regeneration of the build system with newer autoconf+aclocal+automake+libtool tools might help (make a backup first, this step can seriously screw up things).

Comment: Rudi,
Sorry for the delay I hadn't checked to see comments come in.  Anyway, ./configure --version returns:
$ ./configure --version
configure
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.65
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This configure script is free software; the Free Software Foundation
gives unlimited permission to copy, distribute and modify it.

Comment: Also searching for LIBTOOL in configure gets me:
grep LIBTOOL configure
LIBTOOL
LIBTOOL_DEPS="$ltmain"
LIBTOOL='$(SHELL) $(top_builddir)/libtool'
# ### BEGIN LIBTOOL CONFIG
# ### END LIBTOOL CONFIG
# ### BEGIN LIBTOOL TAG CONFIG: CXX
# ### END LIBTOOL TAG CONFIG: CXX

Answer (score 0):

My configure.ac just has:

```
LT_INIT([dlopen])
AC_SUBST([LIBTOOL_DEPS])
```

The LT_OUTPUT is for using libtool for later tests within configure itself, and requires a config.lt to set things up.  I've never had to use it, so I don't know all that entails, but it can't hurt to take that line out and see if that fixes your issue.